# Steps to construct WPF Ribbon based applications

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon-control

Where can I find tutorials or steps to develop WPF Ribbon based applications? The Microsoft page, [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 201](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4)0 doesn't provide any documents for the code samples. For example it has one code sample called RibbonWindowWord.xaml :

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="RibbonWindowSample.RibbonWindowWord"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ribbon="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RibbonWindowSample"
    Title="RibbonWindowWord" Height="600" Width="1000"
    Closing="RibbonWindow_Closing">
    <local:UserControlWord x:Name="WordControl" />
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

what is the programming methodology here?
The channel9 pages which shows tutorials on  Ribbon based interfaces are all for c++ programmers. I'm looking code for C# programmers. Can someone specify resources and tell the differences between the previous WPF codeplex release : http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Southridge%20Lab

channel9 pages
http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/yochay/a-lap-around-windows-7-new-scenic-ribbon
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/yochay/Windows-7-Ribbon-Markup-Overview

Comment: There is FluentRibbon control on Codeplex, that has exactly the same menu as office 2010 applications have. But it requires a RibbonWindow. Anyway, official ribbon can be built using only tags Ribbon-RibbonTab-RibbonGroup-RibbonButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code and 2 examples are on  [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en) just download and install 'Microsoft Ribbon for WPF Source and Samples.msi'. Example just looks like one project but actually contains 2 of them to choose which one you want to run go to App.xaml and uncomment line

```
<Application x:Class="RibbonWindowSample.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="RibbonWindowWord.xaml">
<!--StartupUri="RibbonWindowMvvm.xaml">-->
    <Application.Resources>

     </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

First example is showing how to create all controls in xaml and they are located in RibbonWindowWord.xaml second one is showing mvvm for ribbon RibbonWindowMvvm.xaml.

There are few differences between codeplex version and preview the most important for me is that they switch style to 2010 version and it requires some time to change all the colors.

I found only one [Ribbon Feature Walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx) this is for codeplex version but they are very similar and only Themes & Skins section is not adequate. If you need any other specific help just let me know (I've created different color Theme for ribbon in my project and I've used all the features e.g. contextual tabs). I've noticed this new version is not integrating with chrome library for WPF on Xp.